# C++ Can't access parent method from derived template specialization despite public access

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to access a parent method from a derived template class, but despite using public access everywhere, and "this->" to be safe, I'm getting the error.

```
error: 'class Derived<TagTypeA, int>' has no member named 'insert'
```

I don't know if I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't work out why the Derived class can't access the parent's stuff.

I have code that looks something like below, and also here: https://godbolt.org/z/nMbe4fMnM

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct TagTypeA;

template<typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    std::set<T> data;
    void insert(const T& v) { data.insert(v); }
    void erase(const T& v) { data.erase(v); }
};

template<typename Tag, typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {};

// specialization of Derived
template<typename T>
class Derived<TagTypeA, T> {
  public:
    void call_parent_insert(const T& v) { this->insert(v); }
};

int main() 
{ 
    Derived<TagTypeA, int> foo;
    foo.call_parent_insert(1);
}
```

Comment: `Derived<TagTypeA, T>` has no base classes?

Comment: But it's a specialization of Derived<Tag, T> which has Base<T> as its base class

Comment: Specialisations are basically separate classes and have no relation to the original class

Comment: Unrelated, but mandatory to read: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought because you can't have a specialized class without the unspecialized version that it would know about the inheritance somehow, but I guess not. Anyhow, writing `class Derived<TagTypeA, T> : public Base<T>` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler needs a suspect base class to contain method in question  in order to consider the code legal.

The class described by template specialization

```
template<typename T>
class Derived<TagTypeA, T> {
  public:
    void call_parent_insert(const T& v) { this->insert(v); }
};
```

declares that type `Derived<TagTypeA ,T>` doesn't have base class. There is nowhere it can get `insert` method from. Declaration should be looking like this

```
template<typename T>
class Derived<TagTypeA, T> : public Base<T> {
```

It's not necessary that `insert` would be defined in `Base<T>` at moment of this declaration. It might be defined in a specialization of `Base` later. It matters only at point of instantiation of `Derived` as you cleverly used `this->insert` expression.

If an unspecialized `Derived` never will be used, it can be declared as incomplete  class. Its only purpose in that case is to declare existence of template and this case reduce amount of cryptic template errors in case of misuse.

```
template<typename Tag, typename T> class Derived;
```